# Centering jQuery UI dialog of unknown height - is it possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there a way of making a jQuery dialog opening in the center of the visible window if it's of an unknown height?

I have a dialog that opens a dynamically loaded form of unknown height. When opening it the first time, it's slightly offset towards the bottom of the screen. When I close it and open it again, it seems that the top offset is calculated properly.

I can't know the content height in advance so this is kind of an issue for me.

**edit:** here's an example code

I have two pages - one is the dialog container which instantiates the dialog, and another is the dialog content. When a link is clicked, it's href is used as a target page for the dialog.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(a).click(function(){
        $("#dialog").load($(this).attr('href'))
        .dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 400
        });
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: When you load the content into the dialog, and before you issue the command to open it - you should be able to get the height..?

Comment: Are you able to share some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify height: 'auto' to make the dialog adjust based on its content.

```
.dialog({
    height: 'auto',
});
```

@jon3laze The default value for "position" is 'center', so no need to set it in open callback function.

@eagerMoose There is no need to call the

```
$("#dialog").dialog('open');
```

because dialogs have an autoOpen option, which defaults to true and dialog is being opened immediately after instantiation. The second call to .dialog('open') is ignored.

EDIT: because load is asynchronous the dialog is probably initialized before the content is loaded. Try to initialize the dialog in the load complete.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(a).click(function(){
        $("#dialog").load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
            $(this).dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 400
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Height is set to 'auto' in jQuery UI dialog by default, so this makes absolutely no difference in my case. My guess is that before the dialog is actually drawn (which means before the content is actually loaded), jQuery is unaware of the content height and can't center the dialog accordingly. Setting height to auto makes no difference.

Comment: I think you right about jQuery is unaware of the content height. Try to initialize the dialog in the load complete callback.

Comment: Corneliu, you're absolutely right, I didn't see your reply before I posted one myself. If you edit your answer to match mine, I will happily delete mine and credit your as the answer.

Comment: I have the same problem, basically I have an empty DIV with an ID #dialog-box, so on some anchor click I append my #dynamic-content to my #dialog-box and initialise the $('#dialog-box').dialog({...}) on #dialog-box, it loads the dialog box fine, but it can't detect the height of the #dynamic-content inside the dialog for the first time round, somehow when I click the anchor for second time round it correctly centres it and all looks fine! Any idea anybody? (I tried all of the methods suggested by everyone but none of them worked) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the height before setting the dialog using the [height property](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

> $(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
>
> $(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var h = $(document).height();

    $(a).click(function(){
        $("#dialog").load($(this).attr('href'))
        .dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: h
        }).dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Also, you can chain the `.dialog('open')` on to the end of the call.

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/BZpPH/1/

**UPDATE**

The issue sounds like the position of the content. You can use the `open` event option to have it reset the size upon open. I can't get this to work on jsfiddle because I can't figure out how to get the `.load()` method to work. However I tried this on my own server, defaulted the position to top and it would open center of the screen.

```
$(a).click(function() {
    $('#dialog').load($(this).attr('href'))
        .dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 'auto',
            open: function() {
                $(this).dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give me the height of the page calling the dialog, instead of the page that's being loaded into the dialog?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't understand the question. I will update my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work either, first time round it can't centre it correctly but second time round is fine... however this doesn't really help as that's what jQuery Dialog will do by default!

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was the .load() function. This is an ajax call meaning the .dialog() function gets called before the content was actually loaded, so the content height was practically guesswork.

I managed to solve the problem by defining dialog and its actions inside the .load() function, like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(a).click(function(){
        $("#dialog").load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
            $(this).dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 400
             });
        });
    });
 });
```