# Auto resize width and height with jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, position, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery UI dialog to load ajax content. It is correctly positions the dialog vertically, however, with `width: "auto"` option it does not center it horizontally. It is off-centered, like 100px to the right of center.

Here is my code:

```
$('.open').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#modal").load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
        title: $(this).attr('title'),
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 'auto',
        position: ['center', 'top']
    });
});
```

Any ideas if there's a way to have it auto resize and remain centered?

EDIT: This works:

```
$("#modal").load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
    $("#modal").dialog({
        title: $(this).attr('title'),
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 150],
        create: function(event, ui) {}
    });
});
```

Comment: add css `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;` to your object to set it center, do it.

Comment: jquery resizes it, it will override any default styles

Comment: after create it, I'm sleepy and i cant find it, sorry :D, but when your object insert in your page you can change its position.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering jQuery UI dialog of unknown height - is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474350/centering-jquery-ui-dialog-of-unknown-height-is-it-possible)

Comment: Maybe you should anwser your own question + accept that...

Answer (score 3):

To avoid positioning problems, you should wait for the content to load before creating or opening the dialog. Otherwise:

1. jQuery UI dialog will calculate the width and center of the **empty** div
2. When the content loads, the right side of the dialog stretches to accomodate the content while the left side remains fixed, causing the dialog to appear shifted towards right

Your sample code should be changed to this:

```js
$("#modal").load("/ajax/content.html", function() {
  // callback is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed
  // this refers to the element on which load method was called
  $(this).dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    width: "auto",
    position: { my: "top", at: "top", of: window }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It works for me and is cross browser.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        $('.className').css({position:'absolute', left:($(window).width() 
        - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() 
        - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
        });
});

// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();
```

Creating a dialog from this is should be fairly straight forward.